# Enhancing UIButton: Achieving a More Visible Press Effect

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton

I've noticed that a default, standard, plain-style button doesn't provide a strong indication when it is pressed. For example, consider this plain-style button with its default settings. As you can see, it does not offer a clear visual indicator to show that it is currently being pressed.

[image]

[image]

When examining buttons provided by the OS, such as a photo picker, the visual effect when pressed is more obvious. Could you advise on how I can achieve a similar effect in my UIButton? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Change the style from Plain to Default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply config `setTitleColor` for each state with `style == default`. However, with `Plain`, these configurations do not work. So, you need to apply one of these approaches:

**1. Change style to `Default`, then it will automatically work as expected**

**2. Using new button's UIConfiguration API from iOS 15**

```swift
var config = button.configuration

config?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = config?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { [weak self] input in
    var output = input
    guard let button = self?.button else { return output }
    switch button.state {
    case .highlighted:
        output.foregroundColor = .systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    default:
        output.foregroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
    return output
}

button.configuration = config
```

Comment: But with the button added to a storyboard, no code is needed at all simply by changing the style from Plain to Default.

Comment: @HangarRash you're right, I added an approach in case OP wants to keep the button style as Plain.